# Azure SQL Bacpac import continually fails

Tags: sql-server, azure

Created a new SQL Server and uploaded a Bacpac file to storage.  In the SQL Server area, hit the Import button, filled in the fields and the import starts. It always fails 5 mins later giving me an empty database which then has to be deleted as you can't restore an Azure DB. The Bacpac file was created with MSSMS 2016 CTP3. It couldn't connect directly to the DB server, error said "Bad request". Importing the Bacpac from within the Azure UI also results in "Bad request":-

```
Inner exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageClientException:
The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.; 
Inner exception System.Net.WebException:The remote server returned an
error: (400) Bad Request
```

The DB is an Umbraco website, so nothing huge or controversial I wouldn't have thought. OR is Azure down today?  Getting this far has been a trial as the UI is the worst. However, if anyone can give me any advice on how to get this done I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found an article that stated the Blob Storage had to be "Classic" storage. So tried that and it all worked. The Azure UI is awful, it's too cryptic and there are far too many important things hidden by fancy widgets of limited use IMHO. Anyway, sorted now, hope this helps someone else.